# Return to main menu when game over java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, pong

I'm on the finnishing touches my first game and are having issues returning to the main menu when the player lose the game.

Main(Game) class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Main main = new Main();
```

This is where the menu is added to my frame. The menu itself is a 
  JComponent with graphics and mouselisteners:

```
main.setMenu();
    while (true) {
        menuChoice = meny.getDecision();
        if (i == 0 && menuChoice == 2) {
            main.run(cp);
        } else if (i > 0) {
            main.run(cp1);
        } else if (menuChoice == 0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

public void run(Computer cp) throws InterruptedException {
    if (time == 0) {
```

This is where my frame gets the game's background and so on:

```
        setWindow(data, player, cp);
        time++;
    }

    //Here's a bunch of irrelevant ifs

    } if (cpScore.returnScore() == 10 && time > 0) {
```

Here's where you should return to main menu. What needs to be done
here is basically what the mainmethod does at the absolute 
beginning (add a Mainmenu-frame that takes input for further 
instructions).

```
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"The menu itself is a JComponent with graphics and mouselisteners:"* - and you're doing this from within an infinite `while-loop`. If this is executing within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, then you are blocking it and prevent the UI from been updated. If you're not executing this from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread then you are violating the single threaded nature of the API - either way - it's a mess

Comment: @MadProgrammer It uses the mainthread, if I have understood it correctly. Should that be an issue for the problem of my question? except for the fact that it shouldn't use the mainthread; I've been doing Java for a month so I'm not aiming for flawless code just yet.

Comment: Swing is not thread and is only single threaded. If you attempting to perform operations on the UI from outside the context of the EDT you run the risk of race conditions and other issues which would cause the UI to behave erratically

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way is to set the main menu into its own method with a  boolean value that is initialised to true, and then the menu proceeds so long as this value is true, when you want to return to the main menu, simply change this value back to false, ending the loop and allowing to return to the main menu method.

Answer (score 0):

Create some functions inside of your main class that you can call to do what you are requesting as needed. No one is going to write the code for you, but here are some ideas

```
if (main.isGameOver() || main.isMainMenuRequested()) { 
   main.stopGameThread();
   main.purgeOldGraphicsEtc();
   main.executeMenuThread();
}
```